# Prove by limit definition $\lim _{x\to 3}\left(\frac{x^2-9}{x^3-3x^2-2x+6}\right)=\frac{6}{7}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove, using the limit definition, that

$\lim _{x\to 3}\left(\frac{x^2-9}{x^3-3x^2-2x+6}\right)=\frac{6}{7}$.
I tried to do it this way, but I can’t move forward. Can anyone help me how to continue?
By definition we have
$\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta >0\::\:0<\left|x-a\right|<\delta \:\Rightarrow \left|f\left(x\right)-L\right|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow a-\delta<x<a+\delta \Rightarrow L-\epsilon<f(x)<L+\epsilon.$

Proof:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 3-\delta <x<3+\delta \:\Rightarrow \:\frac{6}{7}-\epsilon <\:f\left(x\right)<\frac{6}{7}+\epsilon &\:\Leftrightarrow& \:\frac{6}{7}-\epsilon <\frac{\left(x-3\right)\left(x+3\right)}{x^2\left(x-3\right)+2\left(x-3\right)}<\frac{6}{7}+\epsilon\\ &\:\Leftrightarrow& \:\frac{6}{7}-\epsilon <\frac{\left(x-3\right)\left(x+3\right)}{\left(x-3\right)\left(x^2-2\right)}<\frac{6}{7}+\epsilon\\ &\:\Leftrightarrow& \:\frac{6}{7}-\epsilon <\frac{\left(x+3\right)}{\left(x^2-2\right)}<\frac{6}{7}+\epsilon \\
 &\:\Leftrightarrow& \:\:?
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

Note that\begin{align}\frac{x^2-9}{x^3-3x^2-2x+6}-\frac67&=\frac{-6 x^2+7 x+33}{7 \left(x^2-2\right)}\\&=\frac{-6x-11}{7(x^2-2)}(x-3).\end{align}So, take $\delta_1>0$ such that $|x-3|<\delta_1\implies|x-3|<1\iff2<x<4$. Then$$7(x^2-2)>7(2^2-2)=14\quad\text{and}\quad|-6x-11|=|6x+11|<35.$$ Therefore$$|x-3|<\delta_1\implies\left|\frac{x^2-9}{x^3-3x^2-2x+6}-\frac67\right|<\frac{35}{14}|x-3|.$$Now, take $\delta>0$ such that $\delta\leqslant\delta_1$ and also that $\delta<\frac{14}{35}\varepsilon$. Then$$|x-3|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{x^2-9}{x^3-3x^2-2x+6}-\frac67\right|<\frac{35}{14}\times\frac{14}{35}\varepsilon=\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid complications, just replace $x\to 3$ by $x=u+3$ with $u\to 0$.

Then $\left|f(x)-\dfrac 67\right|=\underbrace{\left|\dfrac{6u+29}{7(u^2+6u+7)}\right|}_\text{bounded}\times\underbrace{|u|}_{<\varepsilon}\to 0$

It is bounded because $|u|<1\implies \begin{cases}|6u+29|<35\\|u^2+6u+7|\ge |6u+7|\ge\big|7-6|u|\big|>1\end{cases}$

Comment: @zuim I got it the substitution, but could not understand the passages. I tried to open the accounts for understanding, but it was not possible.

Comment: Take $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon)$,then I try to bound the fraction. For the numerator by triangular inequality $|6u+29|<6|u|+29<6\times 1+29=35$ since $|u|<\delta\le 1$. For the denominator $u^2\ge 0$ so $u^2+6u+7\ge 6u+7$ then use $|a+b|\ge ||a|-|b||$ and $7-6|u|>1$ since $|u|<1$. You end up with $|f(x)-\frac 67|<5\varepsilon$.